# maven local custom repo

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

I would use my server as local repo for some jar. I can install single jar into .m2 repo but I can't use this repo into my project's pom. How I use my server as maven repo?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your configuration. Check MAVEN_HOME, settings.xml etc.